# preg_match find regex with or without first capital letter

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

In my project, I need to find a special regex that works if the first letter is uppercase or lowercase. Here are sample strings:

```
user = username
User = username
```

Now, I've tried this regex:

```
'/[^\n]user[^\n]*/'
```

But if first letter is capital, this expression doesn't find anything, so my question is:

What would be the correct regex to find the line containing "user" in it in both cases?

Comment: I don't know the full scope of what you wish to accomplish project-wide, so I'm going to ask if it's necessary to use Regex in this case? Is `user = username` an input string from the client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
$re = "/^user.*$/mi";
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU1wS5/1)

`i` option means "ignore case", and `m` means "multiline", forcing `^` and `$` to match line boundaries. `.` will match any character but a newline (since the singleline mode is not enabled).

Comment: A regex answer with a nice explanation! You don't see this too often :)

Comment: Thanks, this works great,  is it possible to do something similar but to output only a string that comes after the "=" sign? Will accept answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample? Do you mean this: https://regex101.com/r/wN3fN9/1 ? Feel free to update that "fiddle".

Comment: sample is the same as above, in this case I need it to output only "username", not the whole line.

Comment: I would use this regex: `^user\s*=\s*(.*)$` and then only get the captured groups values. See https://regex101.com/r/wN3fN9/2

Answer (score 0):

in regular Expression to ignore the case we should use i
so you can use the following code `'/[^\n]user[^\n]*/i'`